# android_intent Flutter Plugin, i want to launch a app from another app with passing some parameters using android_intent library

Tags: flutter, android-intent, dart

I m using [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) Plugin for flutter and i am unable to launch other app. I am getting error ***"No Activity found to handle Intent"***.

My Code

```
if(Platform.isAndroid) 
{
    final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
        action: 'action_view',
        data: 'package:com.example.app_name', 
        arguments: {'authAccount': "1234@gmail.com"},
    );
    await intent.launch();
}
```

I could not find any sample code related to this, any help will be very crucial.

Thanks in Adv☺

Comment: did u tried url launcher ?

Comment: no, can you tell me how to use that for launcing installed application☺

Answer (score 0):

I also searched the internet, but I didn't find it. Finally I did it like this. It is working, hope it may help someone.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'action_view',
    package: 'com.google.android.gm',
    data:'mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=Issue'
  );
  intent.launch().catchError((e) {
    print(e.toString());
  });
}
else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  launch("mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=Issue").catchError((e){
    print(e.toString());
  });
}
```